# Render turns black when finished

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When blender is rendering I can see my model but at the very end the render goes black and the image saves as a black image. I am using cycles. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: What exactly did you do to fix the the previous issue?

Comment: wohoo you are back! I was rendering two layers at once and my crown was hiding behind one of them apparently. What should I do for this new problem?

Comment: I was hoping I would be able to tell what the current problem is by what you did to fix the previous issue, but it seems @David beat me to it ;)

Comment: @gandalf3 wow, that is a message I did not except to see :) PS with the @ name in the middle of the message it did not alert me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like the *Use Nodes* check mark in the compositer is checked, but the image is not connected to the output.

To fix the above issue you can:

1. If you are not using the compositer on your image, uncheck the *Compositing* check mark in the Properties window.
   [image]
2. If you do want to use the compositer, then you will need these two nodes at a minimum; the *Render Layers* and the *Composite* nodes.
   [image]

Comment: You are the man works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to help me this is my first project on cycles. This community is awesome.

Comment: Blender 3.0, I have the same symptoms, the solution in this post had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. After the render, change the layer in the top right corner from composite to view. Hope this works!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

On the navigation bar, next to the layout names, click the little plus icon. Hover over *Video Editing* and click on it.

[image: example 1]

[image]

If you see any clips on the timeline, delete them and then render your image again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to inadvertently have no denoiser selected.

❶  In the **Properties** window,
  ❷  select the **Render Properties** tab and
  ❸  expand the **Sampling** ⮞ **Render** ⮞ **Denoise** option.

Make sure you have a denoiser algorithm selected.

[image]

        <sub><sup>⮤</sup> Missing Denoiser Algorithm</sub>

If **Denoise** is not checked then this is not the reason your render is turning black.
<sup>(You should select a denoiser anyway, though.)</sup>