# Why when I render an image does it work, but a weird render result comes up?

Tags: rendering

So I made my monkey, added a ground plane, and rendered. Then when it finished rendering, it shows this weird final image that I used as a texture before. The first image shows it in the middle of rendering, the second image shows the render result.[image: image one]
[image: image two]

Comment: The render result may be changed after end of calculations if either there's something in Compositing nodes setup in adjacent way *Or* something in Sequencer *Or* you preview not render result. Make sure it's *Render Result* selected in image list.

Comment: If you uncheck "Compositing" and "Sequencer" in "Post Processing" section of the Render settings, and then render again, do you get a different result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Came back to a blender file, now not rendering](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering)

Comment: This may be your issue: [Render turns black when finished](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14377/2217)

Answer (score 2):

The render is being overwritten by something in the compositor or the sequencer. Un-tic "Compositing," and "Sequencer" in the "Post Processing section of the Render settings, and you should see what you expect.

You might also undo whatever sequencing and/or compositing you have going on in those panes.