# Black image after rendering

Tags: rendering

When I finished rendering, the screen went black and my video didn't export. I need help! It took an hour to finish, and do I really need to start all over again?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Please provide more info on your issue, probably it's already solved like here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/render-turns-black-when-finished. As it's stated now it's just guessing - either something in Video Sequence Editor or in Compositing nodes or something with scene (no lightning etc).