# Render is blank

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I've made a field of grass as a test. When I click on the render button it flashes the progress bar for half a second and the render screen is black

Here is a link to the file on my google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4v-GkVPDQUQWkhzbTFwTHM4dFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: uncheck the sequencer box on the post processing section

Comment: [How do the options in the Post Processing tab work?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/54182/2217) should also be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the *Properties Window > Render Tab > Post Processing Panel* disable the *Sequencer* option

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you! Although it is functioning now, it seems to be rendering from that black screen to a white screen, do you know what might be a fix to that?

Comment: No clue. Check your render settings and lighting setup. When in doubt just create a new scene in the same file, link all relevant objects to the new scene, and render it from there

Comment: I've created a new scene and linked the objects to it but now it only displays a black screen even in render preview. What happens when you try to render it? Does it work for you?

Comment: Working fine on my end it renders albeit everything is pink because of missing textures. Don't forget to import lights and world settings too into your new scene. Also don't forget to change the render engine to cycles otherwise you wont be able to render