# My project shows in the viewer, but is black in the final render

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

[image: screenshot]

So i can see the preview in the backdrop and the image editor, but if i render the picture or the animation, i'll just get black frames. I probably missed something simple, but haven't found the source of the issue yet.

I have rendered images and movies before with the node editor, but something's just wrong this time. I'm not a super experience blender user though.

On another note, blender seems to force windows aero off for me? Would a reinstall fix this or is there another way?

Comment: delete any strips in the VSE. [How do the options in the Post Processing tab work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/54182/2217)