# Can't see anything in final render

Tags: rendering, materials

[image: I have seen the other fixes but didn't find anything]

So the problem is pretty obvious, how do I fix my render? I have checked the transparencies, the "don't show this obj in render", the layers and the light is working.

[image]

Comment: It's good that you have checked other answers but amount of information in your question isn't enough regardless. As rendered image is called Composite then compositing took place. What is in your compositor? What's inside of Video Sequence editor if any? Maybe upload a file on the [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) but add screenshots as well

Comment: Please read through the many possibilities for blank rendering on these links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank

Comment: I have gone thru all the fixes but none of them work

Comment: upload your file so that someone can help you. Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload, and then use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post to add the link to your file to the original question.

Comment: Check the VSE and compositor. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/54184/2217

Comment: Was away for a while, added the link now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Answer (score 1):

As described in the previosuly linked answer: [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) there is a missing link from the render layers to the composite node.

[image]

You are using the compositor, but there is nothing connected to the **composite** (output) node.

[image]

Add a render layers node, plug it to the composite node and render.

[image]