# Blender 3.0.1 Cycles renders image fine (F12) for minutes but at 100% the whole image turns completely black, Eevee works fine

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been unsing Blender for years but am no way an expert. Usually eveything works fine. But today I have the exact same symptoms as in [Render turns black when finished](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/render-turns-black-when-finished), but
the proposed solutions do not work.

- I have a scene that under (Z) -> 8 appears fine.
- In the outliner the disabled(hidden) objects are exactly the same for the viewport and the render.
- Renderer engine is Cycles, I render a still picture (not an animation).
- I have "use nodes" **unchecked** in "Compositor"
- I have only one layer, only one scene, which contains only one collection which contains all the objects, camera, and light.
- If I switch the renderer to Eevee, it renders fine.

I do not have the same symptom as [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) who gets a gray area with a grid: I get a pitch black image. None of the 12 fixes of the accepted answer either works or concerns my situation. Color management is sRGB and I restarted Blender and even the computer.

I do not have the same symptom as [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) either. There is a huge list of fixes there, I just cannot try them all.

This question appears a lot on this forum. The most common answer is to enable/disable the nodes in compositor and/or to Properties (choose this in upper left corner of any frame)->Output properties->Post processing-> check/uncheck compositing and/or sequencer and/or add composite and render layers to compositor and link their image slots. I tried many different combinations, none worked.

At 30%:
[image: 30%]

At 100%:
[image: 100%]

Comment: Er... It does the same thing with the default cube scene. Does it mean there is a bug in Blender 3.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Blender 3.3 from the website instead of using the version 3.0.1 installed via apt and it just worked.

By doing this I loose the nice updating features of apt.

Comment: Well, try another method (for example, adding an additional repository): https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/10/install-blender-ubuntu-complete-guide/amp/

Comment: @quellenform Indeed the snap version is 3.3. Usually apt installed soft work better. Apparently not this time.